# Find any sibling that has matching class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I have a toolbar with buttons. Only one button has the class 'btn-info' for instance to indicate it is currently selected.

But it may not be 'btn-info', it could be btn-anything.

If I click any of the buttons in the tool bar I want to know what the matching class is on which ever button is selected.

I have tried:

```
$('.btn-toggle-group .btn').click(function(){
    var selectedClass = $(this).siblings('button[class^="btn-"]').prop('class')
    $('.btn-toggle-group .btn').removeClass('btn-info btn-primary btn-danger btn-success btn-warning btn-default')
})
```

And...

```
$('.btn-toggle-group .btn').click(function(){
    var selectedClass = $(this).parent().find('[class^="btn-"]').prop('class')
    $('.btn-toggle-group .btn').removeClass('btn-info btn-primary btn-danger btn-success btn-warning btn-default')
})
```

But to no avail.

How can I achieve this? The solution in Jquery or pure Javascript is fine (Javascript is preferred as it is native and faster).

---

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-toggle-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Current</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Deleted</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample HTML? And what are you using the var `selectedClass` for?

Comment: @sbonkosky Added html to edit. The purpose to to drop the "selected" class and re-apply it to the button that has been clicked. But what ever represents what is selected may be different from screen to screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `*` instead of `^`

```
$(this).siblings('button[class*="btn-"]').prop('class');
```

Comment: Is that because it is checking the whole block? i.e. "btn btn-info" so it actually doesn't match because it starts with "btn " (not individual class declarations) ?

Comment: thanks for your help. Do you know how I could tell it to ignore buttons with class '.btn-default'? :)

Comment: @imperium2335 You're correct about the `^` selector. Since the button's class starts with `btn`, the `^` selector will not find it. In order to find the buttons that don't have the class `btn-default` you could use the selector `$(this).siblings('button[class*="btn-"]:not(.btn-default)').prop('class');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to switch to `.attr('class')` instead of `.prop('class')`. DOM elements have properties `className` and `classList`; you could also use those if preferred.